# How can I possibly have 294k of compiled code in my SWF?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, size

I just noticed my size report includes the following:

```
ActionScript Bytes    Location
------------------    --------
            294323    ActionScript 3.0 Classes
```

This seems like **a lot** for what is essentially byte code. I'm not using any images. I have vector art in there but it's mostly straight line geometric stuff, no complicated wiggly art or anything. I'm not using any Components.

My entire codebase comes in at 167k of Actionscript. So how can I be using 294k of byte code?

Comment: 167kB source code to 294kB bytecode (1.6 times the size) doesn't seem *too* outragous depending on how low-level the AS bytecode is and how terse your code, especially considering there's also art in that (perhaps you should check at how much your vector art clocks). For comparision, 2kB Python files can turn in 3kB bytecode files too.

Comment: really? I'd expect that losing identifier names would cause a significant drop in size. Or is that the optimist in me talking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot will come from libraries that you're using in your code. Especially if you're using third-party libraries. For example, I used a system called Eyeblaster that is used to develop online advertisements with functionality such as interchangeable assets, clickthrough tracking, expandable banners and so on.

Just by adding the following to my first frame in the timeline:

```
EB.Init(stage);
```

I already end up with:

```
ActionScript Bytes    Location
------------------    --------
             43616    Scene 1:Frame 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the Flash Professional IDE, go to publish settings->Generate Size report and then we'll all know how it's possible and why you have that big of a swf. :)

**Edit**
If you're using flash builder, try this: http://www.gaboosh.com/blog/2009/12/generating-flash-style-size-reports-in-flex-builder/